# Confusion about fourier series coefficient formulas

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

So I have a bit of confusion regarding the coefficients of a fourier series. On an interval from $[-L,L]$ some places state that:

$$a_n=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)dx, n=0,1,2,3,...$$

$$b_n=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{n \pi x}{L} \right)dx, n=0,1,2,3,...$$

$$a_o=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx$$

However, in other places, I have that:

$$a_o=\frac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx$$

For instance, [This link](https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/fourier-series.html) vs [this link](https://www.quora.com/How-did-Fourier-arrive-at-the-Fourier-series).

Which one is correct? I am a little confused about that. if someone could clarify, that would be awesome!

Comment: It depends how one writes the series. Sometimes people write $\frac{a_0}{2}+\ldots$, sometimes $a_0+\ldots$, in this case additional "2" must be included in the expression for $a_0$

Comment: Very late but thank you! That makes sense.